# discord.py bot undefined error when defined

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

[image]im making a economy bot at the moment and so far i have the code below. Im getting an error that `open_account(member)` is not defined but it's defined as

```
async def open_acount(user):
  users = await get_bank_data()

  if str(user.id) in users:
    return False
  else:
    users[str(user.id)] = {}
    users[str(user.id)]["wallet"] = 0
    users[str(user.id)]["bank"] = 100

    with open("bank.json", "w") as f:
      json.dump(users, f, indent=4)
      return True
```

My code:

```
@bot.command()
async def balance(self, ctx, member : discord.Member = None):
  if not member:
    member = ctx.author
  await open_account(member)

  users = await get_bank_data()
  user = member

  wallet_amount = users[str(user.id)]["wallet"]
  bank_amount = users[str(user.id)]["bank"]

  embed=discord.Embed(title=f"{ctx.author.mention}'s Balance:", color=0x00FFFF)
  embed.add_field(name="Wallet", value= wallet_amount, incline=False)
  embed.add_field(name="Bank", value= bank_amount, incline=False)
  await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

How can i get this to be defined properly? Thanks

Comment: can you post the whole traceback please?

Comment: im not getting an error, i just have the red squiggly lines under  `await open_account(member)` i also added a screenshot

Comment: does the code itself work?

Comment: when i run the command, nothing happens. Im guessing because `await open_account(member)` is not defined so it cant run.

Comment: It is defined, some IDEs throw these warnings out with no reason whatsoever. Try printing something inside the open_account function (right at the beginning of it)

Comment: it did not print what i told it to print.

Comment: I just got it working, there is a typo lmao

Comment: `open_acount` was the defined function haha. Perhaps IDEs don't always throw warnings with no reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You havs a typo in your code: `account` is invorrectly spelled as `acount` as well.